# Disable the 'New' box in Ms Access in favour of a normal dialog

Tags: office365, microsoft-access

When I start Microsoft Access these days, I'm presented with a truly awful New database dialog that I have to click another button in order to browse to a location that I want.

As I'm *always* creating databases in different locations, not simply the one that Microsoft *wants* me to create the database in, how can I simply cut that $*!#& step?...

[image: I hate Access these days! GRRRRR!]

I did see an option for something called Backstage, which I disabled, but that didn't work...

[image: Don't show Backstage]

Comment: Do you mean you want to open the template Access database directly from Access?

Comment: @Lee - No, I simply want to create and open databases using the Open and Save dialog boxes - i.e. take out the extra steps that I'm bound to take, because I don't save everything in one or two folders, like Microsoft wants me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out a workaround for this issue, though it's really not pretty.

Firstly, I've modified the Quick Access toolbar at the top of the Office applications to have the **New**, **Open** and **Save** commands available.  Then I make sure that the **File** > **Access Options** > **Client Settings** > **Don't show the Backstage when opening and saving files with keyboard shortcuts** is true.  Note that, in Word and Excel, the option appears on the **Save** page of the options dialog, under the **Save documents** section.

Despite the fact that the option states '*...with keyboard shortcuts*', the Quick Access commands do seem to also skip the travesty that is the 'Backstage' screen.

Still, with Access, the Backstage does appear on application start, unless you set the option to **Open last used database when Access starts** in the **Advanced** section of the **Client Settings** options. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> does cancel the Backstage, however, returning you to the standard database screen.

When will Microsoft ever realise that they don't know best?  Personally I do not know a single person who wants to store all their documents in one or two folders.  Seven words should bring this crashing back to you, Microsoft - *It looks like you're writing a letter*.